# Handle alternative frame in sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

## Question

When an alt frame is used in a sequence diagram, and one of the two possibility **end** the sequence, how is "legal" to continue?

### example

I need to represent a sequence in wich there are **user** and **atm**

1. the user insert card
2. the atm verify card
3. if card is valid, then it confirm card to user and the sequence continue
4. if not it to user and the sequence **Stop**

can someone represent this simple example?

I made this sequence:

[image]

Is correct?

I assume that the part follow the alt frame imply that "good" case is verified?

Or I need to put all of the sequence of "good case" in the "good case alternative section"?

how can I handle this situation?

Thank's in advance!

Comment: As a side note: it should be `ask for PIN` rather than `insert PIN`. And `invalid card` should be a return message (dashed line).

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38293030/break-stop-execution-in-uml-sequence-diagram-mid-way-inside-alt-opt

Comment: With system sequence diagrams (actor vs system), I prefer a separate diagram for each scenario. That is, one with the "happy path" and another for the "invalid card", etc. I find alt/if/else very difficult to read, especially when there is complexity in the branching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume that the part follow the alt frame imply that "good" case is verified?

No, that assumption is incorrect. The part following the alt frame will be done when either part of the alt frame completes.

> Or I need to put all of the sequence of "good case" in the "good case alternative section"?

Yes, all the steps that belong to the "valid card" alternative of the alt frame need to be shown within that portion of the frame.
If that clutters your diagram too much, you can also draw a seq frame inside the alt frame. The seq frame contains the name of another sequence diagram that describes the steps happening at that point.

Another option is to use a break frame. That would contain the steps for an invalid card (with a guard condition). Either the content of the break frame is executed, or the part of the sequence diagram below the frame.

Comment: You forgot to mention the `break` fragment. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38293030/break-stop-execution-in-uml-sequence-diagram-mid-way-inside-alt-opt

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl: I was not aware of the break fragment, but I added it now.